# Play.current is deprecated in play 2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I am currently using Play.current in the following way.

```
import play.api.{Logger, Play}

object ApplicationConfig {

  val app = Play.current
  def getConfInt(key: String): Option[Int] = {
    val result = app.configuration.getInt(key)
    result
  }
}
```

Since migrating to 2.5, I have a warning saying that it is deprecated with

> "This is a static reference to application, use DI instead"

However, the doc doesn't exactly say how am I supposed to use DI instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your use case you should now use `Environment`, `ApplicationLifecycle` and `Configuration` instead of <s>`Application`</s>

In your case you are actually interested in the configuration so the way to do this in Play 2.5.x would be like this:

```scala
class HomeController @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller {

  def config = Action {
    Ok(configuration.underlying.getInt("some.config.key"))
  }

}
```

The example I provided is for a controller but you can use this approach also on other places in your application. I just didn't like the `ApplicationConfig` object you provided - consider refactoring it when migrating to Play 2.5.x - DI is now the way to go

Comment: Is it fine to do : 
configuration.getInt("some.config.key").getOrElse(-1) ?

Comment: This is perfectly fine! You can see the API doc here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration@getInt%28path:String%29:Option[Int]