# Play: How to replace `Play.current` with DI?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

While trying to write tests I get this warning from Play:

> You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to bring the current running Application into context, please use dependency injection.

I found out that if I add this import, it *magically* solves the problem of the Application in scope:

```
import play.api.Play.current
```

However it warns you that

> method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead

How can I use Dependency Injection to get the same result? This is where I need it:

```
class TestSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite { ... }
```

**Edit**: I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833420/play-current-is-deprecated-in-play-2-5) and I don't see how the answer can give me a clue towards getting an *implicit* `Application`.

Comment: a lot depends which DI you want to use

Comment: I guess it is Guice, if that makes any sense. It should insert as a dependency the equivalent of what `Play.current` inserts globally.

Comment: What exactly do you need from `current`?

Comment: Well the warning says "You do not have an implicit Application in scope", so I need that. Neither `Configuration` or `Environment` give me any clue of what to do with them to get an implicit `Application`. Moreover, if I inject something in `TestSpec` like I do in controllers, tests just don't run anymore. I though everybody got through the same issue at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pointed to [this example](https://github.com/sake92/PlayGuiceExample/blob/master/test/dao/PersonDAOImplSpec.scala#L17) (by @insan-e) that shows how to solve this problem. You can't inject the test class, but you "only" need to override your `PlaySpec` with this:

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneAppPerSuite, PlaySpec}
import play.api.Application
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder

// To avoid repeating the `instanceCache` line below for each DAO
@Singleton
class DaoContext @Inject()(
                        val testDAO: TestDAO
                        // Other DAOs here
)

abstract class BetterSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {
  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(...).build

  protected def daoContext(implicit app: Application): DaoContext = {
    Application.instanceCache[DaoContext].apply(app)
  }
}
```

and the test:

```
class TestSpec extends BetterSpec {
  "Test DAO" should {
    "work" in {
      val dao = daoContext.testDAO
      // test it, finally
    }
  }
}
```

I know, "what the hell????" but it worked.

N.B. Now it can be closed as a duplicate of [Play Slick: How to inject DbConfigProvider in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021022/play-slick-how-to-inject-dbconfigprovider-in-tests?noredirect=1#comment71228382_42021022)