# Play.current is deprecated - Load files in a class used by a Controller (Java Play Framework 2.7)?

Tags: java, playframework

In Play Framework (Version < 2.5) you could load a image file from `/public/images` by:

```
Option<URL> url = Play.current().resource("/public/images/myimage.png");
URL imageurl = url.get();
```

This works in *DEV*-Mode and later in *PROD*-Mode.

What is the correct replacement for `Play.current().resource` to get the correct file path? Or what is the best way to load a file?

Because the normal Java-Method with `MyClass.getClass().getResource("/public/images/myimage.png")` or just `MyClass.getClass().getResource("myimage.png")` (when the file is in the same folder as *MyClass.java*) will not work in *PROD*-Mode.

Thanks for your help!

BTW: Other similar questions ([Play.current is deprecated in play 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833420/play-current-is-deprecated-in-play-2-5) for eaxmple) didn't help, because I don't want to load the configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need inject [Environment](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.7/api/java/play/Environment.html) to get path to resource. It can be accomplished by calling [resource](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.7/api/java/play/Environment.html#resource-java.lang.String-) method.

```
environment.resource("/public/images/myimage.png")
```

Comment: I tried this already. Perhaps I used it wrong. But the following code will always return null in MyController.java:
    private Environment environment = null;

    @Inject
    public MyController(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result mymethod(Http.Request request) {
      URL imageUrl = environment.resource("/public/images/myimage.png");
      // imageUrl is always null!
    }

Comment: It should work. Have you configured assets controller in routes as mentioned here - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/AssetsOverview#The-Assets-controller? You also may try to call `environment.classLoader()` and request file URL via it

Comment: Could you also check if `public` folder exists in `dist`?

Comment: We deleted the line GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(file) in the routes file, because it's also deprecated...  Now it's working. Thank you so much.